# Manipulando evento botão em varios forms

Tags: c#

Bom galera, estou tentando fazer uma manipulação no evento `button`, em vários `forms` diferentes, estou usando C# `WindowsFormAplication`.

Bom, irei tentar dizer minha lógica aqui (espero que entendam).

Tenho um pequeno sistema, nele tem `T_Principal` (veja img abaixo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que nessa mesma tela tem 2 Icon, o primeiro em branco, outro um disquete.

Eu adicionei neles o evento `click`.

Minha duvida é realmente nessa parte agora, veja a imagem logo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, meu `Form T_Agendamentos` esta dentro de `T_Principal`.

Quero fazer um cadastro de eventos, que ao clicar no disquete ele dispara o evento, verifica qual `form` está disparando o evento e executa o código do cadastro. Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se vem ao caso, mas além do proposto pelo Marcelo Nascimento, você pode também criar um `delegate` que receba um parâmetro que é o seu form disparador, pegar esse parâmetro e disparar o método relativo ao form que disparou o evento. É só mais uma opção.

Veja [esse link](http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/c_dlg1.htm) que acho que vai te ajudar.

Comment: poderia da um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade `T_Agendamentos`  não está dentro, está á frente de `T_Principal`, tanto é que ele tem os botões de fechar, minimizar. Se você abrir `T_Agendamentos.ShowDialog()` ele não vai deixar você clicar na janela de trás que é onde está o disquete, tem que usar `T_Agendamentos.Show()`.

Bem mais prático é se o disquete poder ficar em `T_Agendamentos`. A nova janela coleta os dados e manda para a principal arquivar. Mas supondo que isso não é uma opção...

Se as suas classes se chamarem `T_Principal` e `T_Agendamentos`.

Em `T_Principal`

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class T_Principal  : Form
    {
        public T_Principal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Variável que guardará a referência da janela T_Agendamentos
        public T_Agendamentos JanelaAgenda;        

        // Abrir janela de cadastro
        private void NovoCadastro_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.JanelaAgenda = new T_Agendamentos();
            JanelaAgenda.Show();
        }

        // Ícone do disquete clicado. Obter dados preenchidos
        // em T_Agendamentos e cadastrar
        private void Salvar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string agendamento = null;
            string data = null;
            string solicitante = null;
            string local = null;

            // Esse método preenche as quatro variáveis
            this.JanelaAgenda.Cadastrar(ref agendamento, ref data,
                ref solicitante, ref local);

            // Código que faz o cadastro...
        }
    }
}
```

E em `T_Agendamentos`

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class T_Agendamentos : Form
    {
        public T_Agendamentos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Método que passará para T_Principal os dados dos campos preenchidos
        public void Cadastrar(ref string Agendamento, ref string Data,
            ref string Solicitante, ref string Local)
        {
            // No caso as variáveis estão sendo passadas por referência,
            // preencher aqui é o mesmo que preencher de onde o método está sendo chamado
            // Basta passar os dados que foram preenchidos
            Agendamento = "Campo 1";
            Data = "Campo 2";
            Solicitante = "Campo 3";
            Local = "Campo 4";

            this.Close(); // Fecha a janela de cadastro
        }
    }
}
```